# What BIOS default can be changed?

Tags: x86, bios

Standard says something e.g. "INT 10H is video interrupt", "video memory is A0000-BFFFF", but of course the interrupt table can be changed if the BIOS code change. What others can go different to the standard with a custom BIOS?

Comment: If you want to make a custom BIOS, you can change anything you want. Witness EFI, which is different in just about every way. For example, it doesn't use the INT instruction to request BIOS services. Do you have a more specific question?

Comment: @prl No matter what BIOS you use, `8E D8` always mean `MOV DS, AX`. Something like address mapping, port mapping, etc. are what i ask

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean—you want to know what is fixed by the hardware and what is controlled by software. Unfortunately that is far too broad a question for this forum. I suggest you find a PC hardware reference.

Comment: @prl PC hardware references seem also treat BIOS as fixed item, and directly say "INT 15 for sysinfo"